# Hibernate - Handle multiple definitions of a table

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a REST service in Java using Resteasy and Hibernate. This API is supposed to support both older and newer versions of an existing database schema.

In version 1.0 of the database I have a table defined like below:

[image]

Later in version 2.0 the table was renamed, two new columns were added and length of one of the columns was increased. This table now looks like:

[image]

I am planning to create two separate entity classes and based on the version of the connected database use the corresponding entity class.

I would like to know if this approach is OK. If so then is there some better approach for this type of situation.

Comment: Why do you need 2 entities? Why can't you rewrite your entity of version 1 to match your table in version 2?

Comment: I can't do that as few of the fields of entity in version 2 have different field length and some of the fields are made not nullable. This will cause issue for clients running against version 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating two separate entity classes and based on the version of the connected database, I use the corresponding entity class.

Still open to any better solution.